# Entity Framework map private variable instead of properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to use some methods (with parameters) instead of some of properties of some entities in the domain. , and I  want to remove extra properties and just keep the state in variables.

Can I make it?

thank you.

Comment: What would 'Mapping a method' mean? making it available to use in LINQ to Entities query?

Comment: You can't map methods to entity values, so if your table has an ID column, you need and ID property, you can't have just and ID() method.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Well I for one think the question is pretty straightforward. Sometimes state can't easily be represented by simple accessors/mutators (getters/setters) so you manipulate it using methods. What OP needs is a way to have EF ignore methods (which it will) while persisting private variables. Note however that basic OOP principles seldom apply to EF models -- they really represent data layers, not domain models, so one usually encapsulates state in this way at a higher level above EF. That being said, the question is still valid.